# ReactJs input field in child component is not updating

Tags: reactjs

I have to components. First is EditBook Component, which fetches books details and then passes it to the UpdateBook component. However, none of my keystrokes are being binded to the inputbox. Can anyone please help in debugging this.
Here is EditBook -

```
"use strict";

import React from "react";
import ListingHeader from "./listingHeader";
import Listings from "./listings";
import UpdateBook from "./updateBook";
import { Route,Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const BOOK_DETAILS_API_ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost:5001/api/v1/books/';
const header = new Headers({
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
});

class EditBook extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            book: {},
            isLoading: false,
            error: null,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true });

        fetch(BOOK_DETAILS_API_ENDPOINT+this.props.match.params.id,{headers:header})
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
              return response.json();
            } else {
              throw new Error('Something went wrong ...');
            }
        })
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({ book: data.data,isLoading: false })
        })
        .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
    }



    render() {
        const { book,isLoading,error } = this.state;
        return (
            <section className="bg-light" id="portfolio">
                <div className="container">
                    <br/><br/>
                    <UpdateBook book={book} />
                </div>    
          </section>
        );
    }

};

export default EditBook;
```

And UpdateBook is like this -

```
"use strict";

import React from "react";
import ListingHeader from "./listingHeader";
import Notifications, {notify} from 'react-notify-toast';
import InputBox from '../ui/inputBox';

const UPDATE_BOOK_API_ENDPOINT  =   'http://localhost:5001/api/v1/books/';
const headers = new Headers({
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
});

class UpdateBook extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            book:{}
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        if (newProps.book !== this.props.book) {
            this.setState({book: newProps.book});
        }    
    }

    handleChange(e) {
       console.log(this.state.book[e.target.name]); 
       this.state.book[e.target.name] = e.target.value

       console.log(this.state.book[e.target.name]); 
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {        
        event.preventDefault();

        fetch(UPDATE_BOOK_API_ENDPOINT+this.state.book.id, {
            method: 'put',
            headers: headers,
            body:    'isbn_13='+this.state.book.isbn_13+'&isbn_10='+this.state.book.isbn_10+'&title='+this.state.book.title+'&publisher='+this.state.book.publisher+'&author='+this.state.book.author+'&page_count='+this.state.book.page_count+'&date_of_purchase='+this.state.book.date_of_purchase+'&classification='+this.state.book.classification+'&genre='+this.state.book.genre+'&first_published='+this.state.book.first_published+'&description='+this.state.book.description
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
              return response.json();
            } else {
              throw new Error('Something went wrong ...');
            }
        })
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({ book: data.data,bookAdded: true });
            notify.show('book updated successfully!','success');
        })
        .catch(error => {
            notify.show('Something is wrong with something!','error');
            this.setState({ error, isLoading: false })
        });
    }

    render() {

        return (

            <section className="bg-light" id="portfolio">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row " >
                        <div className="col-xs-18 col-sm-12 col-md-12 card text-left">
                            <br/>
                            <h4 className="text-center">Edit {this.state.book.title}</h4>
                            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} type="post" >
                                <Notifications />

                                <div className="centerDiv">
                                    <img src={this.state.book.thumbnail_url} className="form-control text-center"/>
                                    <input type="file" className="form-control-file" id="exampleInputFile" aria-describedby="fileHelp" name="thumbnail_url" />
                                </div>

                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="isbn_10">ISBN_10 (10 characters long string)</label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="isbn_10" placeholder="Enter ISBN 10" name="isbn_10" value={this.state.book.isbn_10 != null ?this.state.book.isbn_10:''} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                                </div> 

                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Enter Title" name="title" value={this.state.book.title != null ?this.state.book.title:''} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                                </div>

                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="description">Description</label>
                                    <textarea type="text" className="form-control" id="description" placeholder="Enter description" name="description" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.book.description != null ?this.state.book.description:''} rows="6">
                                    </textarea>
                                </div>

                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="author">Author</label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="author" placeholder="Enter Author" name="auhtor" value={this.state.book.author != null ?this.state.book.author:''} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                                </div>

                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="publisher">Publisher</label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="publisher" placeholder="Enter Publisher" name="publisher" value={this.state.book.publisher != null ?this.state.book.publisher:''} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                                </div>

                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="page_count">Pages</label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="page_count" placeholder="Enter Pages" name="isbn" value={this.state.book.page_count != null ?this.state.book.page_count:''} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                                </div>

                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="date_of_purchase">Date of purchase</label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="date_of_purchase" placeholder="Enter Date of purchase" name="date_of_purchase" value={this.state.book.date_of_purchase != null ?this.state.book.date_of_purchase:''} onChange={this.handleChange}/>                     
                                </div>

                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="first_published">First Published</label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="first_published" placeholder="Enter First Published" name="first_published" value={this.state.book.first_published != null ?this.state.book.first_published:''} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                                </div>

                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="classification">Classification</label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="classification" placeholder="Enter ISBN" name="classification" value={this.state.book.classification != null ?this.state.book.classification:''} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                                </div>

                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="genre">Genre</label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="genre" placeholder="Enter Genre" name="genre" value={this.state.book.genre != null ?this.state.book.genre:''} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                                </div>



                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Update</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                                </div>    
                            </form>
                        </div>    
                    </div>
                </div>
        </section>    

        );
    }
};

export default UpdateBook;
```

Comment: I think scoping is your issue. using `then`, you get into another scope level where `this.setState` doesn't exist. A way to solve it is to write `let that = this` in your top `handleSubmit` scope, and refer to `that` inside the next scope, i.e. `that.setState`. Not sure if it's best practice(anyone else can chime in), but should work.

Comment: @cbll No, since he is using arrow functions, his scope will stay in the component this#

Comment: Yes, you are correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to call setState in handleChange:

```
 handleChange(e) {
       console.log(this.state.book[e.target.name]); 
       this.setState({ book[e.target.name]: e.target.value });

       console.log(this.state.book[e.target.name]); 
    }
```

Comment: that's actually quite  intresting that the OP uses setState everywhere, except here, maybe you could tell him why manually mutating state is not an option here ;)

Comment: @brub Icepickle thanks for finding the issue. I am kind of ashamed that I did that mistake :(